# VueJs 'filter is not a function' problem in Vuex getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm completely new to frontend development and Vue js. I want to involve a state managment in my application. I can set the state with the response from my API but when I want to filter the results in getter using filter function (getActiveLeagues) I get an error that 'filter is not a function' as if the result was not an array but I think I declared my state with as an array:

```
const state = {
  leagues: [],
};

const getters = {
  getAllLeagues: (state) => state.leagues,
  getActiveLeagues: (state) => state.leagues.filter((league) => league.archivated === false),
};

const actions = {

  async getAllLeagues({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get(`${server.baseURL}/api/league`);
    console.log(response);
    commit('setLeagues', response);
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setLeagues(state, leagues) {
    state.leagues = leagues;
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

and I get an array from API:

[image]

Here is how my Vuex.Store call look like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import posts from './modules/postModule';
import leagues from './modules/leagueModule';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    posts,
    leagues,
  },
});
```

And the result of state watch:
[image]
[image]
Probably it's a stupid problem cause i'm new to this but I can't see what is wrong at the moment.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does your `new Vuex.Store` constructor call look like? Are you passing `state` to it?

Comment: Edit: I uploaded it. I'm passing two modules with state is it right?

Comment: If you try to debug/log your state.leagues, what is the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually haven't used modules and am not sure how it works compared to flat `state`. Best thing is to `console.log(state)` inside the getter to get a better view.

One thing I notice, compared to the docs, is you're not declaring state as a function in the module. E.g.:

```
const state = () => ({
  leagues: [],
});
```

Reference: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

**EDIT** (in response to your new screenshot)

It looks like `state.leagues.leagues` what you're looking for (thanks to module namespacing I guess?), but even *that* is not an array, it's an object with `data` property that is an array.

So start with this:

```
commit('setLeagues', response.data);
```

I think your module state should be receiving it's namespaced substate already, so you shouldn't have to modify anything else. But if it's still broken, try this as well, I'm curious:

```
getActiveLeagues: (state) => state.leagues.leagues.filter((league) => league.archivated === false),
```

Comment: State can be either a function which returns an object or an object literal.
It doesn't really make a difference there, although I do agree he should still console/debug the state.

Comment: @CristianoSoleti oh OK, I would still call plain object a bad habit, since reusing modules could lead to mutated initial state. Just like in Vue itself. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-reuse - but yeah, not looking to be the actual problem here

Comment: Edit: I posted what I get in Vue plugin and console.log. It's actually the mentioned error :/ Ok, anyway I try with state as a function in a moment

Comment: @Pavello see my edit, I think you need to store `response.data` in the commit. `response` itself isn't the array

Comment: It looks like to me as well as the solution.

Comment: Sorry for a little late. Yes! That was it, i works fine with this solution:
commit('setLeagues', response.data); Thanks very much guys